# check for item level

Tags: xslt

Hi i have below piece of xml code.

```
    <toc-div>
                <toc-item num="1.">
                    <toc-title>Introduction</toc-title>
                    <toc-pg>2.001</toc-pg>
                </toc-item>
                <toc-item num="(a)">
                    <toc-title>Transitional arrangements</toc-title>
                    <toc-pg>2.003</toc-pg>
                </toc-item>
                <toc-item num="(b)">
                    <toc-title>Classifying by numbers</toc-title>
                    <toc-pg>2.006</toc-pg>
                </toc-item>
                <toc-item num="2.">
                    <toc-title>Incorporation</toc-title>
                    <toc-pg>2.009</toc-pg>
                </toc-item>
</toc-div>
```

here i want an xslt to give me output as 1 if toc item has a number else i want it to be 2. please let me know how to do it. i know that i can use  condition but i want to know how to form that statement for if node contains a number.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your expected output in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks buddy for the reply, if toc-item is a number i want a variable named chapter and its value to be 1 and if the value of toc-item is not a number, i want chapter value to be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<xsl:template match="toc-item">
   <xsl:variable name="num" select="number(translate(@num, '.', ''))" />
   <xsl:variable name="chapter" select="1 + ($num != $num)" />

   ....
</xsl:template>
```

When used in this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="toc-item">
    <xsl:variable name="num" select="number(translate(@num, '.', ''))" />
    <!-- NaN != NaN evaluates to true(). -->
    <xsl:variable name="chapter" select="1 + ($num != $num)" />

    <xsl:value-of select="concat($chapter, '&#xA;')" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And run on your sample input, this produces:

```
1
2
2
1
```

Comment: thanks friend this solved my problem. but could you please tell me what happens here. thanks

Comment: The line setting the `num` variable uses the `translate()` function to remove the periods from `@num` and then the `number()` function to convert that value to a number. If it cannot be a number, it will have the value `NaN`. The next line adds `1` to the boolean value `($num != $num)`. If `$num` is a number, then this boolean value will be `0` (hence the result will be 1 + 0 = 1). If `$num` is not a number, then this boolean value will be `1` (hence the result will be 1 + 1 = 2).